# Cannot change font in LaTeXIt

Tags: fonts, latexit

I use the following preamble to change the font of my LaTeX documents:

```
\usepackage{mathspec}
\setmainfont[Ligatures={Common,TeX},Numbers={OldStyle,Proportional}]{Calluna}
\setsansfont[Ligatures={Common,TeX},Numbers={Lining,Proportional}]{Calluna}
\setmathfont(Digits,Latin,Greek)[Arabic=Regular,Uppercase=Plain,Lowercase=Plain,Numbers={Lining,Monospaced}]{Calluna}
\setmonofont[Ligatures={NoRequired,NoCommon,NoContextual},Numbers={Lining,Monospaced}]{Monaco}
```

I have the same thing in the LaTeXIt preamble, and it used to work just fine, but today it isn't working. How can I get it to work again?

I didn't update LaTeXIt between the previous time I used it (several months ago) and today. I was using version 2.7.5, which is the same version I used the previous time (when it worked). Just in case, I updated to version 2.10.1, but that didn't solve the problem.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: You need to make sure that LaTeXit is compiling with `xelatex` or `lualatex` in order for this to work. You can set this to be the default in the Typesetting panel of the preferences.

Comment: It is. It’s using XeLaTeX.

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean? Do you get any output? Do errors appear in the log? If so, report the first one that shows up.

Comment: Sorry for not being more specific. There *is* an output, but it’s ignoring the font commands (it’s in the default font).

Comment: And just to head off people posting comments about MWEs, LaTeXit is an equation editor for making snippets to add to Keynote or Powerpoint presentations. There is no MWE that will help the question.

Comment: But you get no errors? If you use this preamble in a document that you compile without using LaTeXit (e.g. from within TeXShop) do you get a correct output?

Comment: Yes, that’s right.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80881/discussion-between-alan-munn-and-rain).

Comment: Only partially. Some of the output is in Calluna, while some is in the default font despite it being characters I know Calluna has (and still some is in the default font because Calluna doesn’t have those characters, but that’s fine). I’m sorry I can’t be more specific, but I’m not at home right now and I can’t test this from work.